# What's the pass in GCC handles const strings?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, elf

What's the pass name in GCC that handles building string array into .rodata section? Would like to write a plugin to intercept also strings in source code, I know there're a bunch of tools in binutils can achieve the same goal, but what if we want to do some postprocessing, for example verify words.

Comment: What does building `.rodata` section have to do with looking at strings (string literals?) from source code? BTW, spell checking GCC plugins have been written before: [in python](https://gcc-python-plugin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/working-with-c.html#spell-checking-string-constants-within-source-code), [in C](https://github.com/enferex/spellhell).

Comment: Yes, I meant string constants/literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read-only data section, also known as `.rodata`, generates after the last step of all rtl passes. You can see how it works in file varasm.c, which lays in `/gcc` folder. Look at section

```
section *
default_function_rodata_section (tree decl)
```

and below.
You can also easily add some functions to intercept data into `asm` file or some other output file here or write an external function.

`varasm.c` file handles the generation of all the assembler code
   **except** the instructions of a function.
   This includes declarations of variables and their initial values.